# numpy.arrayの配列から値を取得したい

Tags: python, numpy

numpy.arrayを用いた配列の中から、取得したい値を検索し、printで表示させるようにしたいです。
しかし

```
 index = np.where(data[powering] == 2.35)
 IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

と言ったエラーがでてしまいます。今配列の中身は、小数も含まれているので、エラーに書かれてある、integerにはできない状態です。どのようにすれば、値を取得できるようにできるのでしょうか。
現在のpythonコードは下記のようになっています。

```
def content(volta, currenting, powering ):
  import numpy as np
  from math import floor
  from math import ceil

  a = np.array([volta, currenting, powering])
  support = np.round(a,２)
  data = np.transpose(support)

  sample = open("test.txt", "w")
  sample.write(str(data))
  sample.close()

  index = np.where(data[powering] == 2.35)
  if index == 2.35:
    vout = 2.9/(2.9 + data[currenting])
    print (str(vout))
    sleep(10)
  else:
    nextvalue = np.round(a,1)
    datatwo = np.transpose(nextvalue)
```

Comment: 例えば [15, 30, 10] という配列で、インデックスが 1.5 だったとき、どんな値になることを期待していますか。インデックスを小数点以下切り捨てて 30、四捨五入して 10、あるいは何らかの補間を、例えば線形補間をして 20 でしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。上記の場合、配列の中に、1.5という値は存在しておりませんので、何も値が入らないという状態にしたいと考えています。しかし、今回、なるべく近い値を、配列の中から見つけることができたら、その値を変数に入れたいと思っていますので、最初上の条件で見つからなかったbaai

Comment: 場合、四捨五入して（上の配列の場合、[20,30,10]となる）条件に合うもの（四捨五入した場合、indexは、2.0となる）をまた探すといった形にしようと思っています。

Comment: そもそも、このコードでやりたいことは何でしょうか。`index = np.where(data[powering] == 2.35)`は、インデックスの配列を返すので、要素の数が複数あると次の `if` はエラーになりますし、要素が１つだけの場合も、入っている数はインデックスなので整数で、`2.35` には絶対に等しくなりません。

Answer (score 1):

配列の要素が持つ「値」は浮動小数点で表される実数でも良いですが、配列の要素を指定する「添字」は整数じゃないといけないと思います。 エラーメッセージは`data[0]`とか、`data[26946,3953964]`とかは解釈できるけど、`data[1.594306850]`とか、`powering=[2.3353, 2.3554, 2.295090]`のときに`data[powring]`とか言われても、何のことか分かりません、と言っているんだと思います。まあ、そうですよね。

やりたいことを察するに、
    currenting=[0.2398, 0.30234,  0.15930, 0.398111, 0.221598]
    powering  =[2.2901, 2.37831,  2.34988, 2.352199, 2.125985]
というリストがあったら、poweringの要素の値が四捨五入して2.35になっている、添字2と3を拾ってくるべし、そして、currenting[2]とcurrenting[3]を使って、voutを計算すべし、ということかと思いました。

そうであれば、あえてnumpy.whereを使って書くなら、例えばこんな風に書けばいいのではないでしょうか。

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# This script was written by norio 2016-09-16.

def calc_v0(currenting, powering,  p0, eps):
    '''
    This function returns a tupple (idx, v0arr), where `idx` and 
    `v0arr` are numpy arrays of integer and float types, respectively.
    Here `idx` is an array of those integers `j` such  that 
    `p0-eps < powering[j] < p0+eps`, and 
    `v0arr` is an array of those values `2.9/(2.9+currenting[j])`,
    for each `j` in `idx`.
    '''

    import numpy as np 
    carr = np.array(currenting)
    parr = np.array(powering)

    idx = np.where(np.logical_and(p0-eps<parr, parr<p0+eps))[0] 
    c0arr = carr[idx] 
    v0arr = 2.9/(2.9+c0arr)
    return (idx, v0arr)


currenting=[0.2398, 0.30234,  0.15930, 0.398111, 0.221598]
powering  =[2.2901, 2.37831,  2.34988, 2.352199, 2.125985]
p0 = 2.350
eps = 5.0e-3
(index, vout) = calc_v0(currenting, powering, p0, eps)

print '# index        vout'
for jj,vv in zip(index, vout):
    print '%5i %20.5e' %(jj, vv)
```

標準出力にはこんな感じのデータが表示されると思います。

```
# index        vout
    2          9.47929e-01
    3          8.79291e-01
```

またnumpyを使わなくても、こんな風にも書けると思います。

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# This script was written by norio 2016-09-16.

currenting=[0.2398, 0.30234,  0.15930, 0.398111, 0.221598]
powering  =[2.2901, 2.37831,  2.34988, 2.352199, 2.125985]
p0 = 2.350
eps = 5.0e-3

index=[jj for jj in range(len(powering)) 
       if (p0-eps<powering[jj] and powering[jj]<p0+eps)]
vout =[2.9/(2.9+currenting[jj]) for jj in index]

print '# index        vout'
for jj,vv in zip(index, vout):
    print '%5i %20.5e' %(jj, vv)
```

もし、添字のリストはとくにいらないなら、こんな感じでもっと簡単に書けると思います。

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# This script was written by norio 2016-09-16.

currenting=[0.2398, 0.30234,  0.15930, 0.398111, 0.221598]
powering  =[2.2901, 2.37831,  2.34988, 2.352199, 2.125985]
p0 = 2.350
eps = 5.0e-3

vout =[2.9/(2.9+cc) for cc,pp in zip(currenting, powering) 
       if (p0-eps<pp and pp<p0+eps)]

print '# vout'
for vv in vout:
    print '%20.5e' %(vv)
```